# perl script running on command line but not in crontab

Tags: linux, perl, scripting, cron, rrdtool

It is very strange, i have many script like following and all running in crontab but following script running on command (./load.pl) line but not inside `crontab`

crontab:

```
0-59/5 * * * * /home/spatel/rrd/load.pl >> /tmp/load.out
```

Notes: 
I also tried following method

```
0-59/5 * * * * /usr/bin/perl /home/spatel/rrd/load.pl >> /tmp/load.out
0-59/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/perl /home/spatel/rrd/load.pl >> /tmp/load.out
```

Somewhere i read cron ignore newline end of the script so i look care of that too

I have put `print` in script and redirect to `/tmp/load.out` i can see that output in `load.out` when cron execute but somehow it is not updating data in side `load.rrd` file.

If i run script on command like `./load.pl` it works! but not inside crontab.

I have set crontab `PATH` whatever `root` use has. I tried all possible way to debug but it is not running inside cron. Here is the place where i get this script, all other script working file in crontab only following one has issue :(   https://github.com/mmitch/rrd

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# RRD script to display system load
# 2003,2011 (c) by Christian Garbs <mitch@cgarbs.de>
# Licensed under GNU GPL.
#
# This script should be run every 5 minutes.
#
# *ADDITIONALLY* data aquisition is done externally every minute:
# rrdtool update $datafile N:$( PROCS=`echo /proc/[0-9]*|wc -w|tr -d ' '`; read L1 L2 L3 DUMMY < /proc/loadavg ; echo ${L1}:${L2}:${L3}:${PROCS} )
#
use strict;
use warnings;
#use 5.010;
use RRDs;

# parse configuration file
my %conf;
eval(`/bin/cat /home/spatel/rrd/rrd-conf.pl`);
die $@ if $@;

# set variables
my $datafile = "/home/spatel/rrd/db/load.rrd";
my $picbase  = "/var/www/mrtg/rrd/load-";

# global error variable
my $ERR;

# whoami?
my $hostname = `/bin/hostname`;
chomp $hostname;

# generate database if absent
if ( ! -e $datafile ) {
    # max 70000 for all values
    RRDs::create($datafile,
         "--step=60",
         "DS:load1:GAUGE:120:0:70000",
         "DS:load2:GAUGE:120:0:70000",
         "DS:load3:GAUGE:120:0:70000",
         "DS:procs:GAUGE:120:0:70000",
             "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:120",
         "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:5:600",
         "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:30:700",
         "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:120:775",
         "RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1440:797",
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:1:120",
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:5:600",
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:6:700",
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:120:775",
         "RRA:MAX:0.5:1440:797",
         "RRA:MIN:0.5:1:120",
         "RRA:MIN:0.5:5:600",
         "RRA:MIN:0.5:6:700",
         "RRA:MIN:0.5:120:775",
         "RRA:MIN:0.5:1440:797"
         );
      $ERR=RRDs::error;
      die "ERROR while creating $datafile: $ERR\n" if $ERR;
      print "created $datafile\n";
  }

# data aquisition is done externally every minute:
my @procs = glob '/proc/[0-9]*';

my $file = '/proc/loadavg';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open '$file': $!";

my $load = <$fh>;

my $p = (scalar @procs);
my $l = (join ':', (split ' ', $load)[0..2]);
print "${l}:${p}";

# update rrd
RRDs::update($datafile,
            "N:${l}:${p}"
            );
$ERR=RRDs::error;
die "ERROR while updating $datafile: $ERR\n" if $ERR;

# draw pictures
foreach ( [3600, "hour"], [86400, "day"], [604800, "week"], [31536000, "year"] ) {
    my ($time, $scale) = @{$_};
    RRDs::graph($picbase . $scale . ".png",
        "--start=-${time}",
        '--lazy',
        '--imgformat=PNG',
        "--title=${hostname} system load (last $scale)",
        "--width=$conf{GRAPH_WIDTH}",
        "--height=$conf{GRAPH_HEIGHT}",
        '--slope-mode',
        '--alt-autoscale',

        "DEF:load1=${datafile}:load1:AVERAGE",
        "DEF:load2=${datafile}:load2:AVERAGE",
        "DEF:load3=${datafile}:load3:AVERAGE",
        "DEF:procsx=${datafile}:procs:AVERAGE",
        "DEF:procminx=${datafile}:procs:MIN",
        "DEF:procmaxx=${datafile}:procs:MAX",

        'CDEF:procs=procsx,100,/',
        'CDEF:procmin=procminx,100,/',
        'CDEF:procrange=procmaxx,procminx,-,100,/',

        'AREA:procmin',
        'STACK:procrange#E0E0E0',
        'AREA:load3#000099:loadavg3',
        'LINE2:load2#0000FF:loadavg2',
        'LINE1:load1#9999FF:loadavg1',
        'COMMENT:\n',
        'LINE1:procs#000000:processes/100',
        );
    $ERR=RRDs::error;
    die "ERROR while drawing $datafile $time: $ERR\n" if $ERR;
}
```

## Update:

Here is the output of script:

```
[root@spatel tmp]# pwd
/tmp
[root@spatel tmp]# /home/spatel/rrd/load.pl 
0.15:0.06:0.01:664
```

Comment: What happens when you invoke it on the command line without being in its actual directory, and execute it using the full path? :)  e.g. **cd ~spatel; /home/spatel/rrd/load.pl**

Comment: @tink i have updated my question with `output` of script, if is run on command line it produce `RRD` graph with data, but if same script ii put in contab then it create the `graph` but `no` data inside the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved:

You won't believe how problem got resolved, I use `perl` instead of `/usr/bin/perl` in `crontab`, I though its best practice to use full `PATH` in crontab but it prove wrong, Still i don't know why and How?

```
0-59/5 * * * * perl /home/spatel/rrd/load.pl
```

Comment: Most likely: Different perl versions found in the path vs. `/usr/bin/perl`. The perl prefix should be irrelevant though - without specifying it, the OS will read the shebang path from your script.

Comment: @Sobrique: I have tried shebang `#!/usr/bin/perl` but that didn't work too. I have only standard perl install with comes with OS.

Comment: Try `which perl` instead :)

Comment: @Sobrique getting same path  `which perl` output 
`/usr/bin/perl` even that link is not symlink because cron doesn't like symlinks

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely an environment problem.

A "cron" scripts starts of with the default system environment (Default PATH, LANG etc.) your .profile, .rc are NOT executed.

So you need to provide all the environment variables PATHs etc. your program requires in the script. This is a bit of a pain for a pure perl script so its probably better to wrap it in a shell script which sets whatever your ".profile" script sets.

Comment: I added full `PATH` in `contab` file on top, also i tried to wrapp `perl` script inside `shell script` but still cron not executing it. Interesting thing is all other perl script running fine. one problem with above script, you can give it a shot on your machine.